# mysql 5.7 - group by not works as expected

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have updated mysql 5.7 from 5.5 recently. after updated, changed the **my.cnf** file into sql_mode = **"STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"** to fix **sql_mode=only_full_group_by** issue.

after these changes, `select * from table where deviceId='1234';`

```
deviceId date
1234     2018-10-20
1234     2018-10-24
1234     2018-10-26
```

select * from (select * from table order by date desc)a group by deviceId;

```
deviceId date
1234     2018-10-20
```

but in 5.5(Expected)

```
deviceId  date
1234      2018-10-26
```

why group by not works in 5.7?

Comment: Its not guaranteed that group by will give you the highest/recent values for non aggregated columns, see [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: MySQL's non-standard group by is a nightmare, and it should not be used. Do yourself a long term favour and switch only_full_group_by on. The reason it is has become the default setting is because it is better this way. Yes, this may require you to unlearn your old group by habits. Unfortunate as that is, blame older MySQL versions for trying to circumvent well established standards.

Comment: It works as I expected

Answer (score 1):

Use max() aggregation and group by

```
select deviceid, max(`date`) as `date` from table where deviceId='1234'
group by deviceid
```